# Webcamlib.dll gives FIleNotFound exception in Win 7 64 bit

Tags: c#, wpf, webcam, webcam-capture

I have a wpf app in which I am using Webcamlib to capture image from webcam. There are lots of stuff over net, how to use it. I developed the app in win 8.1 and everything working fine.
But when I test it in win 7 64 bit, it throws FileNotFoundException. My app configuration is AnyCPU. I tried changing it to x64 and x86, but result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Webcamlib is developed in c++, so it required c++ runtime to be installed on the system. And it should be the same version as your visual studio.